# Multidimensional Array to list by keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14
        [1] => 15
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 10
    )
```

Is there any way that I can convert it in list like
`$var1 = (1,2);
$var2 = (14,15);
$var3 = (9,10);`

Update:

I want to insert database values in list form

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use a foreach loop and make different variable for different array

Comment: `list($var1, $var2, $var3)=array_values($array);`

Comment: Is `(1,2)` an array??

Comment: You *basically* already have that: `$var[1] = [1, 2]`; Why do you need it as individual variables?

Comment: I'm going to save it in list form, I want to see values separated in comma.

Comment: What does that mean, "list form"?

Comment: like results in implode(",",$array)

Comment: So what's keeping you from doing an `implode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably is the easiest and most elegant approach:

```
<?php
$data = [
    1 => [1, 2],
    2 => [14, 15],
    3 => [9, 10]
];
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = array_values($data);
var_dump($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(14)
  [1]=>
  int(15)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(9)
  [1]=>
  int(10)
}
```

Considering some comments you made to the question and other answers it *might be* that you are looking for some output of type string... In that case have a try and play around with something like that:

```
<?php
$input = [
    1 => [1, 2],
    2 => [14, 15],
    3 => [9, 10]
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($values, $key) use (&$output) {
    $output[$key] = implode(', ', $values);
});
print_r($output);
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = array_values($output);
var_dump($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

The output here is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1, 2
    [2] => 14, 15
    [3] => 9, 10
)
string(4) "1, 2"
string(6) "14, 15"
string(5) "9, 10"
```

Comment: This won't work in my problem.

Comment: @user1139323 And "won't work" means what? Your question is very vague, all we can do is guess what you are actually looking for...

Comment: @user1139323 I added some alternative approach which allows for more flexibility towards the desired output format...

Comment: Thank you for understanding and thank you for your answer. It works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic solution, use the following code:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    ${'var'.$key} = implode(',', $value);
}
```

This will create variables with the key name and store the value in it.

Comment: this might be good by I need list format, like implode() result.

Comment: @user1139323 I updated the code.

Comment: `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: @user1139323 then you're not using arrays as `$value`.